# Jinja2 - Hide statements from showing in source code

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a dictionary that i passed from python to javascript

`data`

i used the jinja statements here like this `var mapping = {{ data | tojson }};`

It seems to show up in the source code of the website. Is there anyway i can hide it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean *"show up in the source code"*? What did you expect, and what happened instead?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No. JavaScript needed by the page, whether generated from a Jinja template or not, is going to be visible to whoever views the page source.

The longer answer is that you can 'obfuscate' the JavaScript to make it unreadable to casual readers. Your more technical opponents will take it as a challenge, which will be easy if they can use the Browser's built-in debugging tools.